# firebase push or pull every few seconds?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, push

Given the code and image below for my web app, I am pulling messages from firebase to be displayed on the screen in later code. I am now trying to update the screen with new messages. The question is, Would I be better off getting data pushed instead of pulled? If not, what is the best answer for solving the problem? I don't want to re-pull every message every time. I have never done any push database work, so that is my prediciment as far as not knowing which choice to make.

```
gibber
     Message
         Recent
             -KAMGYcVG0Bu1HRRd7ab
             counter:  0
             date:"2016-02-17T18:16:57"
             description: "Eric Parris"
             groupId: "37xsGJ98WnVhzxu0kgHv"
             lastMessage: "AwGs7+wCn9mvK3sw+/btLsAB4igcQsW+NS6arBHdmKUCkbT..."
             members
             password: "2YgyXODMGV"
             profileId: "Vhzxu0kgHv"
             recentId: "-KAMGYcVG0Bu1HRRd7ab"
             type: "private"
             userId: "37xsGJ98Wn"
```

[image: firebase higharchy]

```
var userId = 'sKdkC6sGYb';///in my code I would be getting current user
var ref = new Firebase("https://gibber.firebaseio.com/Recent");
ref.orderByChild("userId").equalTo(userId).on("child_added", 
function(snapshot) {
    console.log('child_added: '+snapshot.key());
    console.log('value: '+snapshot.val().lastMessage);
    });
```

Comment: 'Pulling' is not something you do in Firebase. There are Queries, and observing events, which is retrieving data by attaching an asynchronous listener to a database reference. I would suggest going through the guide on the firebase site to see what fits your model the best [Retrieving Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html). In your case you can simply add a listener to your node and when new data is added, you app will be notified automagically.

Comment: Oh, an please copy/paste your data structure so we dont have to re-type it when answering.

Comment: My issue is that I know in the Android docs it has listener events to update with changes, but with my javascript web app I do not see how I can do a listener event.

Comment: I am currently using a set interval around the code above, so that every second it looks again to see if there is a new snapshot at that location, but now I am also having to implement a way to detect wether it has seen the message already or not. I was hoping that there would be a better way to do this.

Comment: Isn't that covered in the Firebase JAVASCRIPT WEB GUIDE under retrieving data -> child_added event? That event will notify your app whenever a new child is added.

Comment: Please read the guide that Jay linked to in his first comment. Although you might be faster served by taking this [5-minute tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial). Using `setTimeout()` to get messages from Firebase is an anti-pattern and spending those 5 minutes should be enough to show you the common practices with Firebase.

Comment: Yep! I got it! I ended up getting it last night way before I had realized that I had. I just had an error elsewhere in my code which was causing it to break.